# How to format Partition

Tags: lvm, mkfs

How can I format the following partition on Redhat 5.2?

```
/dev/mapper/VG00-LogVol 148G  111G   36G  76% /u001/app/oracle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Formating" a partition is done by simply creating a filesystem on that device. For example:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/VG00-LogVol
```

But be sure you know what you are doing. You can really destroy data that way.

Comment: Its redhat 5 so isn't it should be mkfs.ext3 /dev/mapper/VG00-LogVol instead *mkfs.ext4*. Yes We already have taken the backup

Comment: You have to decide yourself what kind of filesystem is best for your case. ext3 is probably fine.

Comment: I tried to run the command *mkfs.ext3 /dev/mapper/VG00-LogVol* but its saying that **/dev/mapper/VG00-LogVol is apparently is in use by the system, will not make a filesystem**. Although i have unmounted the filesystem

Comment: a single partition may be multiply mounted (probably almost de-rigueur on a database system) so you need to get down to what the hardware would call that partition at its most rudimentary level.  so my humble suggestion: shutdown all aspects of the running oracle database and disconnect this hard-drive from any remote server, like NFS, then examine the output of "fdisk -l" to see if you can determine something akin to "/dev/sdXY" (e.g. /dev/sdb3) for this partition before you repeat michas' excellent advice up there.

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat distros should have a GUI tool for this called "Disks" installed, and yes, be extremely careful, especially if you're running on a manufacturer-built machine because often times people end up voiding their warranty messing with partitions because the manufacturers almost always have a partition full of recovery tools hidden somewhere.